# Can Oozie shell action create output file on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am new to Oozie and Hadoop. I want to ask if I can run shell action in Oozie and have the output stored to a file on the Hadoop Distributed File System.

Comment: You could put the output directly to hdfs within the shell script itself

Comment: I tried to do so, but I couldn't. All the tutorials i have seen so far uses stdout only and not creating files. Can you please refer me to some examples of put the output to hdfs?

Comment: did you try copy the result to hdfs ?

Comment: you mean to use hadoop fs -copyFromLocal command? I have tried that and it did not succeed as well.

Comment: @KSNidhin How can we put the output directly to hdfs. Could you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

Sure - use the following as the script for the shell action:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo" > output.txt
hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal output.txt /your/path/in/hdfs
```

Comment: So are Hadoop commands not working on the node where oozie is running? You can put `hostname` as line two of the script to spool out the hostname where oozie is running the shell action, then login to that node manually and check everything is correctly set up.

Comment: I have configured the same node to run Hadoop and Oozie. The hadoop command is hadoop fs -moveFromLocal though. The script works fine if I run it locally but it displays bad command or file name when submitted to Oozie.

Comment: How are you defining your Oozie workflow? XML by hand, through Oozie UI or through Hue? In any case, make sure your shell script is uploaded to the Oozie workspace and is mentioned under both the Shell commnad/exec section as well as Files.

Comment: I have modified the shell action workflow provided with Oozie examples. I have uploaded the shell script in Oozie workdpace and it is mentioned under the command/exec section. Here is snapshot of workflow.xml:
'</configuration>
<exec>${EXEC}</exec>
<capture-output/>'

Comment: Add a `<file>${EXEC}</file>` element in your workflow.xml; this is assuming that you are setting ${EXEC} to point to your shell script.

Comment: Here is the error on Hadoop stderr:                                                     Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName                                                   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
This is the same error even without adding the file section.

Comment: @Martin Hammer , I tried your solution but it does not work. Could you please show the complete steps to get this working?

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue and this solved it. You have to add HADOOP_USER_NAME environment variable.
[Go through this once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643775/6001533)

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks