# Oozie - Hadoop commands are not executing (Shell)

Tags: shell, hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hue

I am running a shell script that has hadoop commands.

Getting the following error when executing the same

> Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

I am running a simple shell script with Cloudera Hue - Oozie

However when the script has no hadoop commands, it gets executed sucessfully.

I have set `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` and could see my libs are in

`user/oozie/share/lib/<lib_timestmap>`

Below is the shell script I am trying to run

```
#! /bin/bash
$(hadoop fs -mkdir /<location path>)
```

Wokflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="Shell-copy" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="Shell-copy"/>
    <action name="Shell-copy">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>test.sh</exec>
            <file>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/_rrv9kor_-oozie-38-1455857816.12/test.sh#test.sh</file>
              <capture-output/>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

- The scripts with hadoop commands either throwing the above error or displayed as completed successfully with none of the hadoop commands processed and only the echo's or other shell commands are executed.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the actual stack trace instead of just wondering. Search the oozie log for labels like `job_00000000_0000` then search the YARN logs for that job, cf.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344114/oozie-launch-map-reduce-from-oozie-java-action/34359732#34359732

Comment: Hi Samson., figured out that it was a Permission issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the shell action is that shell jobs are deployed as the 'mapred' user. As the above is deploying the oozie job from a user account other than mapred user , Permission Denied error was thrown.The way to solve this is to set the HADOOP_USER_NAME environment variable to the user account name through which you deploy your oozie workflow.

```
<env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=user_name_goes_here</env-var>
```

Comment: What about simply setting property `user.name` when submitting the Oozie job? *(actually I never tried that - always worked with Kerberos authentication where the "user" is preset)*

Comment: yeah.. you can when you are manually describing your job properties or workflow xml. As I was doing the above with Hue oozie editor, dint explored the option of doing that

Comment: May I know where should I add this environment variable ? is that to .bashrc ? Thanks